# HTTP requests in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to send a request object to a server in a loop 1000 times. The problem statement is basically simulating the movie Office Space where a small amount is withdrawn out of a bunch of bank accounts.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var options = {
    host: 'localhost', 
    path: '/withdraw',
    port: '1234', 
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
}; 



function readJSONResponse(response){
   var responseData = ''; 
    response.on('data', function(chunk){
        responseData += chunk;
    }); 
    response.on('end', function(){
        console.log(responseData);
    }); 
}

var req = http.request(options, readJSONResponse); 


for( var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if(i % 2 != 0) {
        var data = {
            "amount": 0.001,
            "id": i,
            "token": dateToken
        };
    }
}

req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
req.end();
```

I'm expecting that 0.001 is taken out of every account with an odd number. However, when the loop finishes it only takes 0.001 out of the account with the id 999. I've tried calling req.write inside of the for loop as well and that gives

```
_http_outgoing.js:595
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument',
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Rec
eived type undefined
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:595:11)
    at ClientRequest.write (_http_outgoing.js:567:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rlken\OneDrive\Documents\Spring 2019\comp_246\bankhack\wit
hdraw.js:40:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

Comment: Your `for` loop doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Like I said I tried doing the req.write inside the for loop and that gave me the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As p.s.w.g said, the for loop does nothing. In the for loop a variable is being created and then nothing is done with it. 
What you should do as well is each time you want to make a request, initiate it in the for loop so a new request happens each time. What I can expect is happening is the data for the last request only is being sent as this is the last thing stored in the variable data before it is sent.
Also if you want the request ids to start at 1 and end at 1000 then change '<' to '<='.

```
var options = {
    host: 'localhost', 
    path: '/withdraw',
    port: '1234', 
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
}; 

function readJSONResponse(response){
   var responseData = ''; 
    response.on('data', function(chunk){
        responseData += chunk;
    }); 
    response.on('end', function(){
        console.log(responseData);
    }); 
}

for( var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if(i % 2 != 0) {
        var data = {
            "amount": 0.001,
            "id": i,
            "token": dateToken
        };
        var req = http.request(options, readJSONResponse);
        req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        req.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you!